# Excel - Search a cell for text strings from an array and display matched strings

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I have a large-ish spreadsheet of about 1400 rows. One of the columns in that row has been populated from a free-flow text and contains details about numerous items people are requesting. There's no consistency about what's in the text box though.

Image 1 has an example of what the data looks like. C2 is the cell with the data in is. D2 is where I want to extract the list of things from C2 to. If an item appears multiple times I only want it to show once.
[Example image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFX0q.png)

The list where the things I want to look for is on a separate sheet ([Example of list array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3oKV.png)) and the list is defined by the range name "items" and runs from A2:A95.

I'm using Excel365 (despite the example screenshots) and have been trying various solutions from here on SO and various other Excel help pages but can't find anything that will work how I've got things setup. I've nothing against using VBA if that's the only way to do it, but would prefer a simpler solution if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `Named Range` for your reference list so in my formula `ThingsToLookUp` is referencing the range `A2:A9` in my sample file below.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(ThingsToLookUp,C2)),"",ThingsToLookUp))
```

---

[image]

---

Note that you will stumble on some edge cases here with `SEARCH`. For instance, if the string has `Crossbow` you will always output `Crossbow` and `Bow` since the later is a substring of the first. Less important but this solution also outputs the items in the order as they appear on the reference list, not as they appear in the input string.

Comment: Wow. I've been bashing my head against this for ages and 10 minutes after asking here, I have a working answer. That's awesome. This seems to work spot on. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked but keep in mind this is a imperfect solution given your potential substring problem